# Replacing empty values with NULL in $_POST

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to replace empty field values with NULL, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I've tried `array_map`, `array_filter`, and `array_walk`, but to no avail.  Example:

```
function replaceWithNull($var)
{
    if (empty($var) || $var == ' ') {
        $var = "NULL";
    }
}

array_walk($_POST, "replaceWithNull");
```

Instead, it remains empty/blank.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, good catch, both of you.  I figured it had to be something simple.  A shame I can't give the check mark to both answers.

Comment: You may want to check out [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use references for argument passing in order to alter the elements in the array:

```
function replaceWithNull(&$var)
{
    ...
}
```

Otherwise you will be changing only a copy of the variable.

Read about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 5):

You're only modifying the local copy of the variable. You must [pass the value by reference](http://php.net/manual/language.references.pass.php) to modify the value in the actual array:

```
function replaceWithNull(&$var)
{
    if (empty($var) || $var == ' ') {
        $var = "NULL";
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote... I upvoted both this and the reply I selected as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

hey guys look this code:

**config.php**

```
<?php
if( is_array( $_POST ) and count( $_POST ) > 0 )
{
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
    {

        if( is_array( $value ) )
        {
            foreach( $value as $k => $val )
            {
                if( is_string( $val ) )
                {
                    if( empty($val) OR strlen(preg_replace("/(\s+)?/", $val)) == 0 )
                    {
                        $_POST[$key][$k] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if( empty($value) OR strlen(preg_replace("/(\s+)?/", $value)) == 0 )
            {
                $_POST[$key] = null;
            }
        }


    }
}
?>
```

**TEST:**

```
<?php
var_dump( $_POST );
exit;
?>
```

**myApp.php**

```
<?php
include( 'config.php');
//.... your code here....
if(is_null( $_POST['firstname'] ))
{
    echo 'hey men! error!';
}
?>
```